# Custom Listview with scroll area and click area

Tags: android, listview, scroll, click

I have a Custom `ListView`, and each `ListItem`, looks like this:

[image]

I want the left part, with the number, not to be clickable, and when the users touch it, it can scroll the listView.
And the right part, with the textView Question, when it is clicked, to fire up something!

Is there a way to know what part of the ListItem was clicked?

Thank you!

Edit:
the list view is in a ListFragment, like this one:
[image]

and i request focus from touch using:

```
getListView().requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was **much much easier** than i thought!

Lets say, the left area(the scroll area), as it is shown in picture in my question, is wrapped within a Layout.

In the Custom Adapter class, on the `getView` method, just get that Layout, and set a click listener on it, that does nothing!
Just simple as that!

And some code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ....

      final LinearLayout linearLayoutScrollableArea = (LinearLayout) 
      rowView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutScrollableArea);

      linearLayoutScrollableArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //do noth!
                }
            });

       ....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have 2 ListView, clickable and not clickable. When user scroll first ListView, update scroll positions of second view.

Comment: That sounds strange! and scary! Is this the proper way doing it? btw thanks for your answer!